# Generating hex numbers of a certain range using python

Tags: python, hex

I need a simple way to generate a list of hex numbers between certain start and finish value with fast performance using python.

For example:

If I enter 0 and FFF it would pad the output with zeroes to the largest number:

```
000
001
002
003
004
005
006
007
008
009
00A
00B
...
FFF
```

Any suggestions? I'm not a programmer so the best, simplest way to do this is may help me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Using the built-in method [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) and [`format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#format) your output usng `X`(hex) [format specifier](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language):

```
>>> start = 0x000
>>> end = 0xFFF
>>> hex_list = ['0x{:03X}'.format(x) for x in range(int(start), int(end+1))]
['0x000', '0x001', '0x002', '0x003', '0x004', '0x005', '0x006', '0x007', '0x008', '0x009', 
'0x00A', '0x00B', '0x00C', '0x00D', '0x00E', '0x00F', '0x010', '0x011', '0x012', 
...
0xFEA', '0xFEB', '0xFEC', '0xFED', '0xFEE', '0xFEF', '0xFF0', '0xFF1', '0xFF2', '0xFF3', 
'0xFF4', '0xFF5', '0xFF6', '0xFF7', '0xFF8', '0xFF9', '0xFFA', '0xFFB', '0xFFC', '0xFFD', 
'0xFFE', '0xFFF']
```

Note that the output is in string, so if you want to read the hex. value, do:

```
>>> hex_value = int('0xFFF', base=16)
>>> hex_value
4095
```

Comment: You can help me with full code where i want to print all outputs to a txt file. And coming to output we need each output in each line.

Comment: @neworld, have you tried anything by yourself?, I posted this to give you a starter, writing to file on each line shouldn't be that hard to do or find. see here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files